How to restrict flile access/download from IIS server
Our angular app(dist folder) is deployed on IIS server, the app works fine but am able to access(download) the font file directly(without login) from the server using the url from the browser window.
For example: the font file SourceSansPro-Semibold.06fda83f99f5bbf9 is under the following path in server "dist/resources/SourceSansPro-Semibold.06fda83f99f5bbf9"
https://my_server_ip/app_path/resources/SourceSansPro-Semibold.06fda83f99f5bbf9
I am able to download the above file from the server successfully without login :-)
Can we prevent this behavior by having some sort of configuration in the server or in my angular app ?
